# How to create a meta graph in Azure Cosmos DB with Gremlin API

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin

I am trying to figure out how to create a meta model for a graph database on Azure Cosmos DB using the Gremlin API, such as the [meta graph in neo4j](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/schema/meta-graph/), but I haven't been able to find a way so far.

I want to be able to see the entities of my database as nodes, and the relationships among them as edges, without having to load any data yet (so that I can map these nodes and edges programmatically to the data sources, and the sources are only called -and the data loaded- when there is a matching query).

The only information that's relatively close to this that I've managed to find, is about visualizing the whole graph but not its meta structure (although even [this seems to not be possible](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5473b1b1-c4b3-447b-8408-05265be85c1c/show-entire-graph-in-the-data-explorer) yet, or [only possible through external visualization platforms](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/visualize-your-cosmos-db-gremlin-api-graph-data-with-linkurious-enterprise/)).

Is it actually possible to do so? Or Cosmos DB being a schema-free database means that it indeed isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to specify a meta-graph in Azure Cosmos DB's Gremlin API - usually Azure Data Factory, or other application-level solutions are recommended.

Comment: I see, thank you, Luis! I will look into Azure Data Factory then. Also, I was wondering if you know if the Cosmos DB connector from ADF can be used when using the Gremlin API on Cosmos, or if it is still limited to the SQL API and I should try with the Mongo connector. Thanks again!

Comment: ADF is just an orchestrator that uses runtimes, such as .NET. You could create an ADF Activity that just calls the regular Gremlin.Net or the Graph BulkExecutor library.